# How to name the PDF file of output with CMD in R

Tags: r, pdf

I've met a problem when reading [the documentation](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html). It says in the description of the `file` argument:

> a character string giving the name of the file. If it is of the form `"|cmd"`, the output is piped to the command given by `cmd`.

I don't quite get the meaning here.

Does it mean that i can write the statement in R script like `pdf(file = "|cmd", ...)` and use command in the cmd like `Rscript input.R --args 'output.pdf'`?

Here is the example given in the documentation

```
## Test function for encodings
TestChars <- function(encoding = "ISOLatin1", ...)
{
    pdf(encoding = encoding, ...)
    par(pty = "s")
    plot(c(-1,16), c(-1,16), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "",
         xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
         title(paste("Centred chars in encoding", encoding))
    grid(17, 17, lty = 1)
    for(i in c(32:255)) {
        x <- i %% 16
        y <- i %/% 16
        points(x, y, pch = i)
    }
    dev.off()
}
## there will be many warnings.
TestChars("ISOLatin2")
## this does not view properly in older viewers.
TestChars("ISOLatin2", family = "URWHelvetica")
## works well for viewing in gs-based viewers, and often in xpdf.
```

Comment: It is _if_ around the pipe.  If you just do `pdf("myfile.pdf")` it is created as you'd expect.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuette i kinda understand. So the `|cmd` here should be a command like the term given by the documentation as `pdf("|lp -o landscape", paper = "a4r")`, right? Could you please give me a specific example?thx